# Мобильное меню не закрывается

Tags: javascript, jquery

Есть элемент i при клике на который открывается меню и значек меняется на крестик путем замены класса, так же у элемента меняется id что бы я мог закрыть его.Проблема в том, что Js тупо не хочет закрывать элемент, хотя с открытием проблем нет, так же классы и id меняются.В чем проблема??

```
//Menu for small devices
    $('#menu-btn-op').click(function(){
    $('.menu-header-menu-container').css('display','block');
    $('#menu-btn-op').attr('class','fa fa-times');
    $('#menu-btn-op').attr('id','menu-btn-cl');
});


$('#menu-btn-cl').click(function(){
    $('.menu-header-menu-container');
    $('#menu-btn-cl').attr('class','fa fa-bars');
    $('#menu-btn-cl').attr('id','menu-btn-op');
});
```

[image: html]

Comment: весь код в студию

Comment: @Jean-Claude это весь код JS

Answer (score 1, accepted):

К тому моменту как вы вешаете событие `click` на элемент `#menu-btn-op`, этого элемента ещё не существует.

Сделайте так

```js
$('a').on('click', function(){
  $('p').toggle();
  // если нужно дополнительные условия
  if ($(this).is(':visible')) {
    // меню открыто
  } else {
    // меню закрыто
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a href="javascript:">toggle menu</a>
<p style="display: none">Menu element</p>
```